# how do i use textareas and select inputs with angular material design?

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I dont see anything in the documentation about textareas ( or multiline input ) in the docs.
Is there a way to use multiline inputs?

And even though the material design spec doesnt seem to have select inputs, it does have a scrollable drop down menu.  What is the angular material design equivalent to select inputs?

Comment: Unfortunately, they are working material select for angular https://github.com/angular/material/issues/276, we can expect it in January. Only your own custom directive, with material look, are the solutions in the moment.

Comment: Last time i checked textarea was already implemented, you can see the demo here: https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.input

Answer (score 3):

For multi-line input, use [md-input-container](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdInputContainer), with a `textarea` nested inside of it.

For selects: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect

Comment: It looks like on the latest build of angular material 2, this will not work. It will complain that you need an `<md-input>` inside of the `<md-input-container>`